# ExpectedCondition elementToBeClickable pass but element.click fail

Tags: protractor

So I'm writing e2e test for an app and I have a method to fill up an input

```
static async fillInput(el, text = this.randomString()) {
        await el.click();
        await el.clear();
        await el.sendKeys(text);
    }
```

It works great. Well it worked great until I tried it on a field that appeared after clicking on a button. I got a **Failed: element not interactable: element has zero size**. Okay, maybe I4m a little hurry, so my function was updated to be that

```
async fillEmail() {
        const newEmail = CommonMethods.createRandomEmail();
        const emailElement = element(by.css('.block-info input[name="email"]'));
        await browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(emailElement));
        await browser.sleep(5000)
        await CommonMethods.fillInput(emailElement, newEmail);
        return newEmail;
    }
```

I reaaaaally thought it was a delay thing. But no. protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable pass, but fillInput failed with the same error while trying to click on the element.

I checked the css properties too, founc out line-height and font-size are set to inherit and parent has everything set up. width and max-width are set to 100%, element is clearly visible and I can click on it anywhere to get the focus.

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: so what's your error eventually? Failed: element not interactable: element has zero size?

Comment: Yes it was. I managed to make it disappeared by maximizing the window and moving the cursor over the element.